# Reading multiple records of a binary file in c

Tags: c, printf, fopen, fread

I have some issues with reading records from a binary file in C. I couldn't make the loop which supposed to print out all the records work.

Here is the bin file in hex:

```
00000000: 3a5a 3b00 0000 0000 00f9 0f00 0000 0100

00000010: 0000 000c 0000 0000 0000 00fc be00 00c0

00000020: bd01 f2ff 7475 726e 0000 0000 8603 fec6

00000030: 5049 0401 0000 0000 0000 0001 ff0c 0100

00000040: 0000 0000 0100 a103 0000 0000 0000 153f

00000050: 0070 a3c2 0006 0072 6561 6469 6e67 0000

00000060: b0da 4266 2601
```

Here is my struct:

```
struct database {
    long a;
    char b;
    char c;
    unsigned int d;
    short int e;
    char f;
    short int g;
    unsigned short int h;
    double i;
    float j;
    char k;
    short int l;
    char m[8];
    float n;
    char o;
    unsigned short int p;
};
```

Here is the code:

```
int main() {
    struct database testDatabase;
    FILE * fptr;
    fptr = fopen("input.bin", "rb");
    if(fptr == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to open the file\n");

        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
            size_t binData = fread(&testDatabase, sizeof(struct database), 1, fptr);
            printf("%lx, %d, %d, %u, %d, %d, %d, %u, %f, %f, %d, %d, %s, %f, %c, %d\n", testDatabase.a, testDatabase.b, testDatabase.c, testDatabase.d, testDatabase.e, testDatabase.f, testDatabase.g, testDatabase.h, testDatabase.i, testDatabase.j, testDatabase.k, testDatabase.l, testDatabase.m, testDatabase.n, testDatabase.o, testDatabase.p);
        }
        fclose(fptr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
3b5a3a, 0, -7, 15, 1, 0, 0, 12, -0.000027, -0.093750, 1, -14, turn, -32513.761719, P, 1097
1, 1, -1, 268, 0, 0, 1, 929, 0.000080, -81.718750, 0, 6, reading, 109.343750, f, 294
```

Output received:

```
10cff01000000, 0, 0, 60882945, 0, 0, 0, 16149, 13355573734043312712829005875651725547656734885377284021247501284200881177315085086490075484700128964300844457791245158354643854211712148535380203348191089215811377052096766486815074582332713845623445000466297982674842156415393442601424125952.000000, 17255938721382828255215616.000000, 110, 0, ��Bf&, -724237366876331573248.000000, �, 0
```

Comment: Your for loop does i < ; which if compiles would probably be i < 0 nothing printed. You need the record count if you are doing it this way, then i <= record_count ;

Comment: @slkjdfarrangement,  `printf("%lx, %d, %d,...` is not valid with also seeing the value of `binData`.  What is it?  Also suggest `struct database testDatabase;` --> `struct database testDatabase = { 0 };` to zero fill it.  I suspect `fread()` simply failed.

Comment: As @chux has pointed out, you should check the return value of `fread` before attempting to use the result of that function. Did you verify that it returned the value `1`?

Comment: that can be the reason. I'll look into that

Comment: The length of _the bin file_ is suspicious.  I suspect it is for 2 `struct database`, in which case, the record length is 51 - very unusual - unless the data was _packed_.

Comment: It was for 2 struct database. That was the reason why i tried to use a loop to read it and failed

Comment: slkjdfarrangement, Code needs `... char o;  unsigned short int p; };` --> `... char o;  unsigned short int p; } __attribute__((packed));` or equivalent.  Yet I still suspect code is not reading anything.

Comment: slkjdfarrangement, Removing `size_t binData =` is a step backwards.  Better to put back in and report its value.

Comment: righto, i'll do it

Comment: slkjdfarrangement, Tip: for now, replace all %d with %x, %f with %a to aid in debugging.  [TTFN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TTFN).

Comment: WIth the interleaving of datatypes in the struct, you may need to read the appropriate number of bytes into each element individually to account for `padding`.... Give that a try...

Comment: Please insert the line `printf( "%zu\n", sizeof(struct database) );` at the start of the program and tell us what value it prints. That way, we can see how much padding the `struct` has. Please also tell us what value `printf( "%zu\n", sizeof(long) );` prints. On some platforms, a `long` is `8` bytes, on some it is `4`.

Comment: I've just found out the problem, and obviously, structure padding is behind this. Using __attribute__((packed)); for struct helped solving this. I still have to rewrite my code tho it's outside my course's specs

Comment: @slkjdfarrangement: Note that you [may answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). However, you may also want to consider improving your question, by adding some additional details, such as those requested in the comments section.

Comment: Note that you don't have to read the whole `struct` at once from the file. You could also read one `struct` member at a time. In that case, padding would not be an issue.

Comment: that was supposed the right way to do this based on my seniors. Does it mean I have to use multiple fread() to read each member simultaneously?

Comment: @slkjdfarrangement: Yes, you will have to call `fread` once for every `struct` member if you want to do it the way that I suggested.